# How to avoid duplicates of form fields and validations of forms accross angular application?

Tags: angular

I am new to angular.

I am building a application which have contact and subscribe form, which is common in websites. Both of these forms have first name, last name and email fields. I was duplicating html markup and validation for these two forms.

So I decided to extract common fields to a separate component and inorder to  avoid duplication but I am struggling to pass values from child component to parent and keeping submit button disabled incase of invalid input in child component.

My current code is given below.

**personalinfo.component.html**

```
<div [formGroup]="personalInfoForm" novalidate>
  <div class="firstName">
    <mat-form-field>
      <input matInput placeholder="First Name" 
             formControlName="firstName">

      <mat-error [hidden]="personalInfoForm.hasError('required', 'firstName')">
        Please provide first name
      </mat-error>

    </mat-form-field>
  </div>

  <div class="lastName">
    <mat-form-field>
      <input matInput placeholder="Last Name" formControlName="lastName">
      <mat-error [hidden]="personalInfoForm.hasError('required', 'lastName')">
        Please provide last name
      </mat-error>
    </mat-form-field>
  </div>

  <div class="email">
    <mat-form-field>
      <input matInput placeholder="Email" formControlName="email">

      <mat-error *ngIf="personalInfoForm.hasError('required', 'email')">
        Please provide an email
      </mat-error>
      <mat-error *ngIf="personalInfoForm.hasError('pattern', 'email') && 
                       !personalInfoForm.hasError('required', 'email')">
        Invalid email
      </mat-error>
    </mat-form-field>
  </div>
</div>
```

**personalinfo.component.ts**

```
import { Component, OnInit, Input } from '@angular/core';
import { Validators, FormBuilder, FormGroup } from '@angular/forms';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-personalinfo',
  templateUrl: './personalinfo.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./personalinfo.component.scss']
})
export class PersonalinfoComponent implements OnInit {

  readonly EMAIL_REGEX = "[a-zA-Z0-9.-_]{1,}@[a-zA-Z0-9.-_]{1,}.[a-zA-Z]{2,}";


  personalInfoForm: FormGroup;

  constructor(private fb: FormBuilder) {

    this.createPersonalInfoForm();
   }


   createPersonalInfoForm() {

    this.personalInfoForm = this.fb.group({
      firstName: ['', Validators.required],
      lastName: ['', Validators.required],
      email: ['', [Validators.required, Validators.pattern(this.EMAIL_REGEX)]],

    });
  }
  ngOnInit() {
  }

}
```

**contact.component.html**

```
<div class="form-contact" flexLayout="row" fxLayoutAlign="center">


  <form [formGroup]="contactForm" 
        novalidate 
        (ngSubmit)="sendMessage(contactForm.value, contactForm.invalid)">


    <app-personalinfo></app-personalinfo> 



    <div class="subject">
      <mat-form-field>
        <input matInput
               placeholder="Subject"
               formControlName="subject" >
        <mat-error   *ngIf="contactForm.hasError('required', 'subject')">
          Please provide a subject
        </mat-error>
        <mat-error   *ngIf ="contactForm.hasError('minlength', 'subject') &&
                            !contactForm.hasError('required', 'subject')">
          Minimum 5 characters
        </mat-error>

      </mat-form-field>
    </div>

    <div class="message">
      <mat-form-field>
        <textarea matInput 
                  placeholder="Message" 
                  matTextareaAutosize 
                  matAutosizeMinRows="5" 
                  matAutosizeMaxRows="10"
                  formControlName="message">
        </textarea>
        <mat-error  *ngIf ="contactForm.hasError('required', 'message')">
          Please provide a message
        </mat-error>
        <mat-error   *ngIf ="contactForm.hasError('minlength', 'message') &&
                            !contactForm.hasError('required', 'message')">
          Minimum 10 characters
        </mat-error>
      </mat-form-field>
    </div>

    <button mat-button 
            color="primary" 
            type="submit" 
            [disabled]="contactForm.invalid">
            Submit
    </button>

  </form>

</div>
```

**contact.component.ts**

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { FormControl, Validators, FormBuilder, FormGroup } from '@angular/forms';
// interface with fields (firstName, lastName and etc)
import { User } from '../user';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-contact',
  templateUrl: './contact.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./contact.component.scss']
})
export class ContactComponent implements OnInit {


  contactForm: FormGroup;

  constructor(private fb: FormBuilder) {

    this.createContactForm();
   }


   createContactForm() {
    this.contactForm = this.fb.group({
      subject: ['', [Validators.required, Validators.minLength(5)]],
      message: ['', [Validators.required, Validators.minLength(10)]]
    });
  }


  ngOnInit() {
  }

  sendMessage(user, isInvalid: boolean)
  {
      if(!isInvalid){

        console.log(user);

         console.log(user.firstName);
         console.log(user.lastName);
         console.log(user.email);
         console.log(user.subject)
         console.log(user.message);

      }
  }

}
```

I found several questions, but things are not clear. Any help would be highly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just create a reusable component for your shared form.

**shared-form.component.ts**

In your `shared-form.component` you define your shared `FormControls`.

- firstName
- lastname
- email

What you need next is to get hold of your [FormGroupDirective](https://angular.io/api/forms/FormGroupDirective) in your component. With this Directive you can call `Submit` and `Reset` outside of the scope of your `[formGroup]`

With this setup your SharedForm is ready to use for remote control! :)

Your `shared-form.component.ts` will look something like this:

```js
import { Component, ViewChild, Optional } from '@angular/core';
import { FormGroup, FormBuilder, FormGroupDirective, Validators, NgForm } from '@angular/forms';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-shared-form',
  templateUrl: './shared-form.component.html',
  styles: []
})
export class SharedFormComponent {

  @ViewChild(FormGroupDirective) fgd: FormGroupDirective;

  public form: FormGroup;

  get emailCtrl() {
    return this.form.get('email');
  }

  constructor(private fb: FormBuilder,
              @Optional() fgdParent: FormGroupDirective) {
    this.createForm();
    if (fgdParent) {
      fgdParent.ngSubmit.subscribe(() => this.fgd.onSubmit(null));
    }
  }

  createForm() {
    this.form = this.fb.group({
      firstName: ['', Validators.required],
      lastName: ['', Validators.required],
      email: ['', [Validators.required, Validators.email]],
    });
  }
}
```

`shared-form.component.html`

```html
<div [formGroup]="form" novalidate>
  <div class="firstName">
    <mat-form-field>
      <input matInput placeholder="First Name"
             formControlName="firstName">
      <mat-error>
        Please provide first name
      </mat-error>
    </mat-form-field>
  </div>

  <div class="lastName">
    <mat-form-field>
      <input matInput placeholder="Last Name" formControlName="lastName">
      <mat-error [hidden]="form.hasError('required', 'lastName')">
        Please provide last name
      </mat-error>
    </mat-form-field>
  </div>

  <div class="email">
    <mat-form-field>
      <input matInput placeholder="Email" formControlName="email">
      <mat-error *ngIf="emailCtrl.hasError('required')">
        Please provide an email
      </mat-error>
      <mat-error *ngIf="emailCtrl.hasError('email') && !emailCtrl.hasError('required')">
        Invalid email
      </mat-error>
    </mat-form-field>
  </div>
</div>
```

---

**personalinfo.component.ts**

Your `PersonalinfoComponent` is nothing else then a wrapper for your `SharedForm`

`personalinfo.component.html`

```html
<mat-card>
  <h3>Subscribe</h3>

  <mat-card-content>
    <app-shared-form #form></app-shared-form>
  </mat-card-content>

  <mat-card-actions>
    <button mat-raised-button color="primary" type="button" (click)="onSubmit()">Submit</button>
    <button mat-raised-button type="button" (click)="form.fgd.resetForm()">Reset</button>
  </mat-card-actions>
</mat-card>
```

`personalinfo.component.ts`

```js
import { Component, ViewChild } from '@angular/core';
import { SharedFormComponent } from '../shared/shared-form/shared-form.component';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-personalinfo',
  templateUrl: './personalinfo.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./personalinfo.component.css']
})
export class PersonalinfoComponent {

  @ViewChild(SharedFormComponent) formComp: SharedFormComponent;

  onSubmit() {
    this.formComp.fgd.onSubmit(null);
    if (!this.formComp.form.valid) { return; }
    console.log('Ready to make an ajax call: ', this.formComp.form.getRawValue());
  }
}
```

I am not a big fan with disabled button if the Form is not valid. Because the user can't see any validation errors when he tries to hit the Submit button. A much more better User-Experience would be, if the User hits the Submit Button the form will trigger the validation and the User can see whats wrong with the Form. This is btw fully implemented in Angular Material FormField.

There are a few examples of how you can trigger the Submit Event from `ParentComponent` to your `ChildComponent`. As we get hold of the `ChildComponent` via `ViewChild`-Decorator we can call `onSubmit()` on the `FormGroupDirective` and the validation gets triggered. To Reset the form simply call `resetForm()`.

---

**contact.component.ts**

The use case with `ContactComponent` is very similar to `PersonalinfoComponent`.

As far as the View is rendered we can inject the `ChildForm` (SharedFormComponent) into our `ParentForm` (ContactForm)

```
ngAfterViewInit() {
  this.contactForm.addControl('personalInfo', this.childForm.form);
}
```

For now on ContactForm is Valid if and only if the ChildForm is valid.

But the really cool stuff here is again the powerful DI from Angular.

If we are using the SharedForm a lot in our Application we can inject the parent `FormGroupDirective` in our SharedFormComponent as an Optional Dependency. So everytime SharedFormComponent is getting wrapped inside a parent `FormGroup` it automatically gets hold of the parent `FormGroupDirective`. Now we can delegate the submit event form the parent to the child.

```
constructor(private fb: FormBuilder,
            @Optional() fgdParent: FormGroupDirective) {
  this.createForm();
  if (fgdParent) {
    fgdParent.ngSubmit.subscribe(() => this.fgd.onSubmit(null));
  }
}
```

`contact.component.ts`

```js
import { SharedFormComponent } from './../shared/shared-form/shared-form.component';
import { FormGroup, FormBuilder, Validators, NgForm } from '@angular/forms';
import { Component, OnInit, ViewChild, AfterViewInit } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-contact',
  templateUrl: './contact.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./contact.component.css']
})
export class ContactComponent implements AfterViewInit {

 @ViewChild(SharedFormComponent) childForm: SharedFormComponent;

  contactForm: FormGroup;

  constructor(private fb: FormBuilder) {
    this.createContactForm();
  }

  createContactForm() {
    this.contactForm = this.fb.group({
      subject: ['', [Validators.required, Validators.minLength(5)]],
      message: ['', [Validators.required, Validators.minLength(10)]]
    });
  }

  ngAfterViewInit() {
    this.contactForm.addControl('personalInfo', this.childForm.form);
  }

  onSubmit() {
    if (!this.contactForm.valid) {
      return;
    }
    console.log('Contact Form is Valid!', this.contactForm.getRawValue());
  }

  onReset(fgd: NgForm) {
    fgd.onReset();
    this.childForm.fgd.onReset();
  }
}
```

`contact.component.html`

```html
<mat-card>
  <mat-card-title>
    <h3>Contact</h3>
  </mat-card-title>

  <mat-card-content>
    <form [formGroup]="contactForm" #fgd="ngForm" novalidate (ngSubmit)="onSubmit()">

      <app-shared-form #childForm></app-shared-form>

      <div class="subject">
        <mat-form-field>
          <input matInput placeholder="Subject" formControlName="subject">
          <mat-error *ngIf="contactForm.hasError('required', 'subject')">
            Please provide a subject
          </mat-error>
          <mat-error *ngIf="contactForm.hasError('minlength', 'subject') &&
                    !contactForm.hasError('required', 'subject')">
            Minimum 5 characters
          </mat-error>

        </mat-form-field>
      </div>

      <div class="message">
        <mat-form-field>
          <textarea matInput placeholder="Message" matTextareaAutosize matAutosizeMinRows="5" matAutosizeMaxRows="10" formControlName="message">
      </textarea>
          <mat-error *ngIf="contactForm.hasError('required', 'message')">
            Please provide a message
          </mat-error>
          <mat-error *ngIf="contactForm.hasError('minlength', 'message') &&
                    !contactForm.hasError('required', 'message')">
            Minimum 10 characters
          </mat-error>
        </mat-form-field>
      </div>

    </form>
  </mat-card-content>

  <mat-card-actions>
    <button mat-raised-button (click)="fgd.onSubmit(null)" color="primary" type="button">
      Submit
    </button>
    <button mat-raised-button type="reset" (click)="onReset(fgd)">Reset</button>
  </mat-card-actions>
</mat-card>
```

I created a small working example to make a lot stuff more easier to understand:
https://stackblitz.com/github/SplitterAlex/stackoverflow-48931808

Just follow the source code here:
https://github.com/SplitterAlex/stackoverflow-48931808